# how to keep precision from numpy's array

Tags: python, xml, numpy

Like Following.

```
>>>a=numpy.array([-97.173125220360362], dtype=double)
>>>b=[]
>>>b.append(a)
>>>b
-97.173125220360362
```

**But if I assign the value to `List` directly**. It will lost the last number, like following:

```
>>>b=[-97.173125220360362] 
>>>b
-97.17312522036036
>>>b=[]
>>>b.append(-97.173125220360362)
>>>b
-97.17312522036036
```

And I found I can't change the last number. like following

```
>>>b=[-97.173125220360364]     
>>>b    
-97.17312522036036    
>>>numpy.double(b)    
-97.173125220360362 not -97.173125220360364
```

**PS**
I need to save many double numbers from `numpy.array` into a XML file. I found I lost all of the last numpy by read the XML file.
**For example**.
If I save  `-97.17312522036036` into the XML. and read the value as a string from XML. then convert the string into double value. That will round my vaule

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing here is effectively the difference in either `__repr__` or `__str__` for the numpy float data type and the built in float datatype.

Inconsistent.

```
>>> repr(a[0])
'-97.173125220360362'
>>> repr(float(a[0]))
'-97.17312522036036'
```

Consistent.

```
>>> '%0.18f'%float(a[0])
'-97.173125220360361709'
>>> '%0.18f'%(a[0])
'-97.173125220360361709'
```

Either way, their representation in memory is the same.  The extra "precision" that you see in one result is really just noise:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>l', struct.pack('>f', float(-97.17312522036036)))
(-1027450716,)
>>> struct.unpack('>l', struct.pack('>f', float(-97.173125220360362)))
(-1027450716,)
>>> struct.unpack('>l', struct.pack('>f', a[0]))
(-1027450716,)
>>> struct.unpack('>l', struct.pack('>f', float(a[0])))
(-1027450716,)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same number, it just happens to be formatted differently when it's `numpy.double` rather than `float`:

```
>>> x = -97.173125220360362
>>> x
-97.17312522036036
>>> np.double(x)
-97.173125220360362
>>> np.double(x) == x
True
```

Comment: Also, `repr(np.double('-97.17312522036036')) == '-97.173125220360362'`

Comment: whatever the last number you giv. it will be `2`. For example x = -97.17312522036036n, the echo of np.double(x) is -97.173125220360362